# How to change value of object which is inside an array using react redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to implement a function called 'addToCart' which is responsible for adding products inside a 'cartItems' state whenever user clicks on a specific product. I am able to add as many products as i want .
But whenever i click on a specific product, i want to change its qty if it is already inside my cart instead of adding duplicate items. I want to increase items qty no matter how many times i click the specific product.
I have uploaded some of my code to make it more concise.

> initialState

```
  const initState = {
    cartItems: []
    }
```

> cartReducer

```
case CART_ADD_ITEM:
  const item = action.payload;
  const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);
  if (existItem) {
    return {
      ...state,
      cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
        x.product === existItem.product ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 } : x
      ),
    };
  } else {
    return {
      cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
    };
  }
```

> cartActions

```
export const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
      payload: {
        name: data.name,
        price: data.price,
        product: data._id,
        qty,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response);
  }
};
```

> productComponent

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart } from "../actions/cartActions";
const Product = ({ product, qty }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    dispatch(addToCart(product._id, qty));
  };
  return (
    <div className="product-card" onClick={addToCartHandler}>
      <h3>{product.name}</h3>
      <p>{product.price}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have taken a close look on the code. The implementation seems make sense. I have just added two things in the `cardReducers.js`

1. wrap the return object using `()`. If you are doing using the `? :` operator and the short hand syntax of `map`, not sure if the compiler will work properly to know that you want to return an object
2. for the `else` case, add the `...state` for in case you have more properties in the future.

```
case CART_ADD_ITEM:
  if (existItem) {
    const isCurrentlyExist =  x.product === existItem.product 

    return {
      ...state,
      cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => (isCurrentlyExist ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 } : x)
    };
  } else {
    return {
      ...state,   //if you have other state in the future
      cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
    };
  }
```

Comment: i tried your solution but vs code automatically removes those brackets and again its same condition.

Comment: Check my updated answer. If this is also removed by the vscode plugin. Directly make a new object and incrementing the ```qty``` by 1. Then return it in the ```map``` and see if it really the problem.

Comment: now i am able to increase qty but for only once. i cant increase qty from 2.

Comment: How is your code written now? And you mean increment each time by 2?

Answer (score 0):

Your code for handling the case "if an item already exists" is very close to working. The problem is that you're spreading the `item`, the one you're receiving from the `action.payload`. This will cause to "reset" the item `qty` and it will not increment the `qty`. Instead you should do it like this.

```js
case CART_ADD_ITEM: 
  const item = action.payload;

  const isItemInCart = state.cardItems.find(
    (itemInCart) => itemInCart.product === item.product
  );

  if (!isItemInCart) {
    return {
      ...state,
      cardItems: [...state.cardItems, item],
    };
  }

  const newCartItems = [...state.cartItems].map((itemInCart) => {
    if (itemInCart.product !== item.product) return itemInCart;
    // notice that we're returning the itemInCart instead of item
    return {
      ...itemInCart,
      qty: itemInCart.qty + 1,
    };
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    cardItems: newCartItems,
  };
```